# How to make jQuery AJAX request with a HTTP Handler in SP10?

Tags: jquery, event-handlers, ajax, visual-web-part

I'm developing a SP 2010 Visual Web Part that needs to load some data via AJAX.

I found [this very helpful article](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/11/sp2010-ajax-part-3-using-jquery-ajax.html) but I'm having some doubts about it.

I have the Visual Web Part project, inside I have the Visual Web Part and some other files. The article says I need to create an .ashx file that will acts as an HTTP handler.
So that's what I did, I created a "MyHandler.ashx" in the root of the project and put the `WebHandler` directive. But I'm not sure about the `Assembly` directive.

Then it says we need to create an implementation to the handler and point it to it. I believe I have that part ok.

Then I need to make the actual client call via jQuery. Here's the part I don't know how to do it because I don't know the url where the .ashx is being deployed (if it's even being deployed...).

I'm trying:

```
$.get('/_layouts/SomeNamespace/MyHandler.ashx', ...)
```

But it's not working... again, don't know the handler's url...

I'm pretty new at Sharepoint development, so please don't be harsh =)

Thanks!

Here are simplified versions of my handler's files.

**MyHandler.ashx**

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="SomeNamespace.MyHandler" CodeBehind="MyHandler.cs" %>
```

**MyHandler.cs**

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }


        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.Write("From the handler at " + DateTime.Now);
        }

        // bunch of methods
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<handlers>` node in the web.config defines the location of the HTTP Handler. Have a read at Chris's article again, and look at the Web Config Modification he does.

Comment: Read again. He says there are 2 options to associate the handler to its implementaion. Either you do the WebHandler directive thing OR you go for the webconfig modification. I'd rather not touch the webconfig.

Comment: Ahh, did you create a Layouts mapped folder in visual studio? If not, do that, it'll place the ashx in the SharePointRoot where it'll become accessable via the /_layouts path.

Comment: Yeah, I just did that being almost sure it would work. But it didn't. I have an "Images" mapped folder and it works, I can access the images. But I created a "Layouts" mapped folder, placed the .ashx inside but still can access it.
Do you know if I need to add it to the Package or the Feature to actually make it deployable?

Comment: Forget it. It was already added to the Package when created the Layouts mapped folder. Wonder if it's something about the .ashx itself. Maybe I didn't define it well.. I do not have the Assembly directive, don't know what to put in it.

Comment: 1) Look into the file system itself (C:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server etensions\14\template\layouts) to see if the file is created. 2) The assembly directive should have the fully qualified name of your assembly -Visual Studio 2010 has a shortcut to this in the form of a token - $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$ - and you'll need to tell Visual Studio to parse the ASHX file to do the token replacement (here's how to do that, adding ashx instead of svc): http://scottcurrier.wordpress.com/2011/06/28/visual-studio-token-replacement-tip-wcf/

Comment: It's working... I was mistyping the url ¬¬ stupid. I'm not getting the correct response though because I'm getting an error, but it is actually finding the handler. I'll try to see what's the error. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm getting the following error (detailed in the Event Log): Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpParseException 
    Exception message: Could not create type 'SomeNamespace.MyHandler'. 

So, I'm pretty sure is something about my assembly declaration missing or wrong. Any idea?